# Need a Test Framework for testing IOS Native + React native App

Tags: ios, react-native, automated-tests

I need help in choosing an efficient framework to test my app, which is 50% React Native based and 50% on IOS Native.

Query 1 : Do I have an option using XCtest to validate React Native screens??

Query 2 : If i can't use XC test for RN, then which one will be better for use (in terms of test coverage and penetration) Appium or Calabash so that i can cover testing both RN and IOS Native screens??

Answer (score 0):

i have used **appium + Robotframework** to develop a Test Framework . Here is a reason to choose RF and appium

if you integrate appium library in robotframe work, you would be able to do almost similar thing which can be done by any other languages with lot of ease and control.

Taking example of your assignment in hand

1) You can define Test cases
2) Your test cases would be platform independent , that means similar test cases can be run on android/ios platform with change of parameters(capabilties)

3) You can Create a seprate variable file and then pass it with main file during run time (check pybot -V)

4)You dont need to be worry about reporting part , all the reports would be generated and with betterdrill down options

**Additional advantage**

1) There are lots of inbuilt libraries, which will help you to do your task easily

2) You can create your own custom library and import in Robotframework

3) You would be able to drill down till last variable where the problem is with help of RobotFramework Reports, which will save lots of time

In Nutshell i can say Robotframework provide a building block to your framework where you just need to worry about the functional aspect of your program